# Using Python's ctypes to pass/read a parameter declared as "struct_name *** param_name"?

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes, structure, sane

I am trying to use Python's ctypes library to access some methods in the scanning library [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/).  This is my first experience with ctypes and the first time I have had to deal with C datatypes in over a year so there is a fair learning curve here, but I think even without that this particular declaration would be troublesome:

```
extern SANE_Status sane_get_devices (const SANE_Device *** device_list, SANE_Bool local_only);
```

First of all, I've successfully dealt with `SANE_Status` (an enum) and `SANE_Bool` (a typedef to `c_int`).  Those were both simple.  That first parameter, on the other hand, is causing me all sorts of grief.  I'm unfamiliar with the "`***`" notation to begin with and my tracer bullets so far have yielded nothing more than garbage data.  How do I format the input to this function such that I can read back a list of my Python structure-objects?  For reference, the C structure being referenced is:

```
typedef struct
{
    SANE_String_Const name; /* unique device name */
    SANE_String_Const vendor;   /* device vendor string */
    SANE_String_Const model;    /* device model name */
    SANE_String_Const type; /* device type (e.g., "flatbed scanner") */
 }
SANE_Device;
```

Where `SANE_String_Const` is defined as a `c_char_p`.

My Python/ctypes version of this object is:

```
class SANE_Device(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("name", c_char_p),
        ("vendor", c_char_p),
        ("model", c_char_p),
        ("type", c_char_p)]
```

Suggestions on what I should pass in such that I can get the expected behavior (a list of structure-objects) out of this?  All responses appreciated.

**Update 1:**

Using the following, I was able to retrieve a correct SANE_Device Python structure:

```
devices = pointer(pointer(pointer(SANE_Device())))
status = libsane.sane_get_devices(devices, c_int(0))
print status, devices, devices.contents.contents.contents.name
```

However, 1) yuck and 2) that seems like it would only work if there is a single result.  I can't len() on `devices.contents.contents` or `devices.contents.contents.contents`.  How am I to determine the number of results?  The SANE docs specify that "If the function executes successfully, it stores a pointer to a NULL terminated array of pointers to SANE_Device structures in *device_list".  Suggestions?

**Update 2:**

I was able to pass an ten-item array and then access the first element using:

```
devices = pointer(pointer(pointer((SANE_Device * 10)())))
status = libsane.sane_get_devices(devices, c_int(0))
print status, devices, devices.contents.contents.contents[0].name
```

However, ten is obviously an arbitrary number and I have no way of determining the actual number of results.  Trying to access `devices.contents.contents.contents[1].name` when only one device is connected causes a segmentation fault.  There must be a proper way of dealing with variable-length constructs like these in ctypes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `const SANE_Device ***` is a three-level pointer: it's a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a constant SANE_Device.  You can use the program [cdecl](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/man_pages/cdecl1.html) to decipher complicated C/C++ type definitions.

According to the [SANE documentation](http://www.sane-project.org/html/doc012.html), `SANE_get_devices()` will store a pointer to a NULL-terminated list of pointers to SANE devices if successful.  Thus, the proper way to call it is to declare a variable of type `const SANE_Device **` (i.e. a pointer to a pointer to a constant `SANE_Device), and pass in the address of that pointer:

```
const SANE_Device **device_list;
SANE_get_devices(&device_list, local_only);  // check return value
// Now, device_list[0] points to the first device,
// device_list[1] points to the second device, etc.
// Once you hit a NULL pointer, that's the end of the list:
int num_devices = 0;
while(device_list[num_devices] != NULL)
    num_devices++;
// num_devices now stores the total number of devices
```

Now, this is how you would call it from C code.  I've skimmed the documentation on ctypes, and it appears that you want to use the `byref` function to pass the argument by reference, and that the value you pass should be a POINTER to a POINTER to a SANE_Device.  Note the distinction between `pointer` and `POINTER`: the former creates a pointer to an *instance*, whereas the latter creates a pointer to a *type*.  Thus, I'm guessing the following code will work:

```
// SANE_Device declared as you had it
devices = POINTER(POINTER(SANE_Device))()  // devices is a NULL pointer to a pointer to a SANE_Device
status = libsane.sane_get_devices(byref(devices), c_int(0))
if status != successful:   // replace this by whatever success is
    print error
else:
    num_devices = 0
    // Convert NULL-terminated C list into Python list
    device_list = []
    while devices[num_devices]:
        device_list.append(devices[num_devices].contents)  // use .contents here since each entry in the C list is itself a pointer
        num_devices += 1
    print device_list
```

[Edit] I've tested the above code using a very simple placeholder for `SANE_get_devices`, and it works.

Comment: My goodness this is an extraordinarily thorough answer and, better yet, it works!  And better even than that, I'm not sure I ever would have come to this on my own.  Thanks Adam!

Comment: That's a very nice answer Adam.